# Header file issue with xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, nsobject

I have a subclass of NSObject, but I have a problem with header file, when I run the project, it shows me this:

[image: Error returned]

[image]

and it allows me to add this, but directly this logical error is returned: "@end must appear in Objective-C context"

[image]

**I precise that with Xcode6 I didn't have that issue with this** Does anyone knows how to fix this frustrating issue ?

EDIT:

that's a constants file, do not pay attention to the file's name, here is .m file:

```
#import "CUSBoxes.h"

const int defaultCount = 10;
const long int repeat = 25000;

const NSString *defaultDescription = @"If any layout issue is related, change default values of each box you want to display";


@implementation CUSBoxes

@end
```

Comment: Might be somewhere in another .h or .m file, @end is missed or misplaced.

Comment: All worked with Xcode 6, and it seems that the problem is only with NSObject subclass files, all is working with other files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error causes you missed @end or invalid character in one of the .h file you used in your project. I have came across with this error, this error not exist in same files it throws check for other header files to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) You might missing @end in any of the Header file.Check one by one all .h file which has @interface section,should be ended with "@end".

2) If everything looks good then Try cleaning project or Restart Xcode.(In my case,It worked).